# Compile entire project from another project

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, csharpcodeprovider

I have a Windows Forms application, which I use to generate resource files. I'm trying to add such functionality to this application, that would allow me to compile another Windows Forms application into an executable, that would have these resources included. However, I'm stuck on that compile another Windows Forms project part.

I tried to follow [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dohollan/archive/2010/08/09/programmatically-invoke-the-c-compiler.aspx), my code so far looks like this:

```
CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
parameters.IncludeDebugInformation = true;
parameters.GenerateInMemory = false;
//parameters.TreatWarningsAsErrors = true;
parameters.WarningLevel = 3;
parameters.CompilerOptions = "/optimize";
parameters.OutputAssembly = "Program.exe";

CSharpCodeProvider codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
CompilerResults results = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(parameters, new string[] { "Program.cs" });
```

I'm not exactly sure, if I'm doing this correctly (if I should compile Program.cs file). Program.cs file looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace example
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

And when I try to compile it with the code above, I get this error:

```
Line number 16, Error Number: CS0246, 'The type or namespace name 'Form1' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I'd really appreciate if you guys could help me out, I've never compiled anything from another project.

Comment: How can you just compile a single file and expect it to work?

Comment: I think you should use CompileAssemblyFromFileBatch passing all the files like Program.cs and Form.cs and Form.Designer.cs and so on

Comment: Rather than 'hope', read up on the compiler documentation. That said, just call `msbuild project.csproj` and be done with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the other project you want to compile is project.csproj, reference Microsoft.Build.Framework and use this code:

```
var globalProperty = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Configuration", "Debug"}, { "Platform", "Any CPU" } };
var buildParameters = new BuildParameters(new ProjectCollection()) { Loggers = new List<ILogger> { new ConsoleLogger() } };
var buildRequest = new BuildRequestData(@"C:\example\project.csproj", globalProperty, "4.0", new[] {"Build" }, null);
BuildResult buildResult = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(buildParameters, buildRequest);
```

Or you could just wrap the MsBuild.exe

```
var p = new Process(); 
p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe");
p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"C:\example\project.csproj";
p.Start();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however while using your first method, buildResult.OverallResult is Failure and the project does not build.

Comment: This will be because the other project doesn't compile, rather than the code above. What are the errors?

Comment: I get The OutputPath property is not set for project 'project.csproj', but the project.csproj file looks like this http://pastebin.com/pvqXvm1N so with Configuration|Platform Debug|Any CPU it should be set..

Comment: Ok I found the error, Platform in your configuration should not contain that space, so AnyCPU is correct while Any CPU is not. Please fix it. Thank you for your help, I'll accept this answer.